# Getting the difference between 2 adjacent elements of a named vector in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, vector

I wonder how can I get the difference (e.g., using `diff()`) between each 2 adjacent numbers in each row (2nd element - 1st element, 3rd element - 2nd element etc.) of `res` output below?

```
library(effects)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat2.csv')

fit <- lm(math ~ time*ses + I(time^2)*ses, data = dat)

(res <- allEffects(fit, xlevels=list(ses=0:1, time=0:7))[[2]])

   time
ses         0         1        2        3        4        5        6        7
  0 0.4986515 0.8179641 1.093079 1.323995 1.510713 1.653233 1.751555 1.805679 # diff bet. each two adjacent points
  1 0.5326918 0.9433164 1.304973 1.617661 1.881381 2.096133 2.261917 2.378733 # diff bet. each two adjacent points
```

Comment: Example `t(apply(mtcars[1:3,],1,diff))`.

Comment: @user2974951, doesn't seem to work here. `res` is not a data.frame or matrix.

Comment: Have you tried coercing it to a matrix or df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `summary(res)$effect` to get the matrix that you are interested and then use `apply` with `diff` or subtract the columns directly.

```
mat <- summary(res)$effect
t(apply(mat, 1, diff))
```

```
mat[, 2:ncol(mat)] - mat[, 1:(ncol(mat) - 1)]

# time
#ses         1         2         3         4        5          6          7
#  0 0.3193126 0.2751144 0.2309163 0.1867182 0.142520 0.09832187 0.05412374
#  1 0.4106246 0.3616564 0.3126883 0.2637202 0.214752 0.16578391 0.11681577
```